# Malformed Json Error on http request

Tags: httpresponse

Hey all I am getting an error and cannot for the life of me figure out why.  Thanks in advance for help!

Error is:

> Failed to invoke future method 'public static void pushToLead2(String)' on class 'SomethingAPI' for job id 'something'

> caused by: System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object

> Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
> Class.SomethingAPI.pushToLead2NotFuture: line 153, column 1
> Class.SomethingAPI.pushToLead2: line 102, column 1

Code:

```java
@future(callout=true)
public static void pushToLead(String accountId) {
    auth(false);
    Account account = [SELECT Id, PersonEmail, Name, Phone, Utm_Source__pc, Utm_Campaign__pc,
                    Utm_Term__pc, Utm_Medium__pc, Utm_Content__pc, Something_Lead_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accountId];
    HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
    req2.setEndpoint('https://wwwSomething.com/api/v1/lead' + (account.Something_Lead_Id__c != null ? '/' + account.Something_Lead_Id__c : ''));
    req2.setMethod(account.Something_Lead_Id__c == null ? 'POST' : 'PUT');
    req2.setHeader('x-api-token', auth);
    req2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    Map<String, Object> bodyMap = new Map<String, Object>();
    
    SomethingLead ll = new SomethingLead();
    if (lead.Something_Lead_Id__c != null) {
        //   ll.id = Integer.valueOf(account.Something_Lead_Id__c);
        // ll.skip_salesforce_update = true;            
    }
    ll.email = account.PersonEmail;
    ll.source = 'Salesforce';
    ll.name = account.Name;
    ll.phone = account.Phone;
    ll.utm_source = account.Utm_Source__pc;
    ll.utm_campaign = account.Utm_Campaign__pc;
    ll.utm_term = account.Utm_Term__pc;
    ll.utm_medium = account.Utm_Medium__pc;
    ll.utm_content = account.Utm_Content__pc;
    
    bodyMap.put('lead', ll);
    
    req2.setBody(JSON.serialize(bodyMap));
        
    Http http2 = new Http();
    HttpResponse res2;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        res2 = http2.send(req2);
    } else {
        res2 = new HttpResponse();
        Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 10000000));
        res2.setBody('{"status":"ok","lead":{"id":' + randomNumber + '}}');
    }
    
    System.debug('ALL: ' + res2.getBody());
    
    // Attempt relogin on 500
    if (500 == res2.getStatusCode()) {
        auth(true);
        req2.setHeader('x-api-token', auth);
        res2 = http2.send(req2);
    }
    
    
    LeadResponse resBody = (LeadResponse) JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(), LeadResponse.class);
    Account updAcc = new Account(Id = account.Id);  
    
    if (resBody.status == 'ok' && account.Something_Lead_Id__c == null) {
        ll = resBody.lead;
        updAcc.Something_Lead_Id__c = ll.id;
        runOnce = false;
        
    }
    
    updAcc.Push_To_Something__c = false;
    update updAcc;
}
```

Comment: Your error references `pushToLead2()`, but you have included `pushToLead()`. Is this the correct code?

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure a specific answer is possible without seeing the JSON being deserialized.

Comment: Sorry for confusion @DavidReed pushToLead2 calls pushToLead class

Comment: The stack trace shows the error in `pushToLead2`, not in this code.